# Understanding the Plane Symmetric Metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, symmetry, space-expansion

I don't understand as to what is the point of having a plane symmetric universe / metric at all? I mean shouldn't any physically sensical cosmological model (e.g. FLRW Model) entail a spherically symmetric metric?
What scenarios are modelled by planar symmetry? I am relatively new to GR and cosmology, and would be very glad if some one can explain.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you saw people studying such metrics? That would help in tailoring an answer to your experience.

Comment: I understand that the field equations do admit plane symmetric solutions with appropriate choice of stress tensor, have seen them in the book by Stefani (Exact Solutions to Field Equations), also have come across research papers where for instance researchers one would be interested in calculating plane symmetric solutions to the field equations for the case of dust. I understand the problem grinding, but the basic purpose is unclear : the plane symmetric metric models what ? Is matter distribution in the universe plane symmetric ? Or is planar symmetry merely of theoretical interest?

Comment: For similar reasons, I don't understand the point of solving the field equations in cylindrically symmetric scenarios. In lieu of homogeneous isotropic universe, why deviate from spherical symmetry at all ?

Comment: This [article](https://export.arxiv.org/pdf/1101.4668) has a history section about cylindrically symmetric solutions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Einstein's equations are, in general, *extremely* difficult to solve. As such, exact solutions are valuable for a number of reasons - they are pedagogically useful, they provide insight about symmetries and their consequences, they may serve as limiting cases or rough approximations to more realistic models, etc.
2. Spherical symmetry is by no means a general feature.  In fact, it's rather hard to come up with a realistic physical system which *does* have spherical symmetry.  Stars, planets, and (presumably) most black holes possess non-zero angular momentum, which means that at *most* they are cylindrically symmetric (though if the angular momentum is small then a spherically symmetric model may suffice).
3. Planar symmetry is used e.g. to model the presence of [domain walls](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.39.3571), or to embed (in the non-technical sense) [two-dimensional toy models](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9407024) in 4D spacetime.

> I don't understand the point of solving the field equations in cylindrically symmetric scenarios. In lieu of homogeneous isotropic universe, why deviate from spherical symmetry at all?

4. As stated above, anything with non-zero angular momentum cannot be spherically symmetric. Large structures which *do* have angular momentum - spiral galaxies, accretion disks, etc - tend to be very obviously non-spherical, but may have approximate cylindrical symmetry.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and effort to write out the details, will look at the links provided and find out more about planar symmetry, do understand the point regarding cylindrical symmetry, cheers!